# RegExp for remove first and last char and turn ending double slashes into single

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following Javascript code to obtain the inner string from an RegExp:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name,func){
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};

RegExp.method('toRawString', function(){
    return this.toString().replace(/^.(.*).$/,"$1");
});
```

The purpose of this, is to avoid in string double quoting. For example, if you have a Windows file path "C:\My Documents\My Folder\MyFile.file", you can use it like the following:

```
alert(/C:\My Documents\My Folder\MyFile.file/.toRawString());
```

However it is not working for ""C:\My Documents\My Folder\" since it causes syntax error. The only way to avoid it is to keep double quoting at the end of the string. Thus it will be written

```
alert(/C:\My Documents\My Folder\\/.toRawString());
```

The fact is any odd number of back slashes on the end of the string will be an error, so all ending back slashes must be double escaped. It will not be hard to use a multiple line small implementation, but are there any single RegExp solution?

**NOTE**

When using `toRawString` the `RegExp` object for `this` is usually NOT going to be used for any other purpose except for that method. I just want to use the syntax of RegExp to avoid double back slashes in source code. Unfortunately the ending double slashes cannot be easily avoid. I think another workaround is to force a space at the end but that is another question then.

**UPDATE**

I finally solved the "another question" and posted the code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26289/javascript-regular-expression-literal-as-string-literal).

Comment: I guess if we're really trying to be hacky, you could do this:
`(function(){/*C:\My Documents\My Folder\MyFile.file*/}).toString().split('*')[1]` and you won't have to escape any backslashes!

Comment: A great point, but not good enough though as you may still need to escape `/` or `[]`, `()`. I come up with a solution that only need to escape `]` in the last position of a `]` sequence (for example the last one in ']]]]]')  with `][`, by use not only regular expression, and also char groups. See my UPDATE, there is a link to the code.

Comment: No, the only two things you must escape in that example are `*` and `*/` all the other sequences will be fine: `]`, `)`, `/` etc..

Comment: Emm... The only thing that is not convenient : there is a too long sequence in addition to the content string.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I get what you're trying to do! It's hacky : )

Try something like:

`return this.toString().slice(1, -1).replace(/\\+$/, '\\')`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Aha, that looks pretty like what I am looking for!

Comment: The only thing I can see is that if the input string end with double double slashes it is still an error. so it should be `replace(/(\\\\)(?:\\|$)/,"\\")`

Comment: Or better yet: `replace(/\\+$/, '\\')`

Comment: Or better yet: `replace(/\\{2,}$/,'\\');`

Comment: @sstur 's answer is incorrect as it does not work for odd numbers of back slashes.

Comment: I thing @Jan Turoň actually did a better job. :)

Comment: They produce the same result, mine says "replace one or more trailing backslash with one", his says "replace two or more trailing backslash with one". The result is the same (since replacing one with one, does nothing) yet I use my notation for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

This produces a syntax error:

```
/C:\My Documents\/
```

But that regular expression could be written correctly like this:

```
/C:\\My Documents\\/
```

Or like this:

```
new RegExp("C:\\\\My Documents\\\\")
```

I think your function is just fine and is returning a correct result.  Regular expressions just can't end with an unpaired backslash.  It's not that you're double escaping - you're just escaping the escape character.

This would produce an error too:

```
new RegExp("C:\\My Documents\\")
```

A regular expression like this, for instance, can't be written without a pair of backslashes:

```
/C:\\What/
```

Without the second backslash, \W would be interpreted as a special character escape sequence.  So escaping the escape character isn't only necessary at the end.  It's required anywhere it might be interpreted as the beginning of an escape sequences.  For that reason, it might be a good rule of thumb to always use two backslashes to indicate a backslash literal in a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for that information, I think I understand most of those concepts. However, in my case I am looking for a way to avoid the double back slashes in source code, so that I can just copy paths from Explorer and that paste into the code without manually change single slashes into double. So that is the motivation of developing the function.

Comment: @Earth Engine: Like I mentioned above, there are lots of cases where pasting a path into a regular expression won't work without modification.  It would be easier to just use a quick function to escape the backslashes, i.e. x.replace(/\\/,"\\\\")

Comment: or better yet replace(/([\\$^&*.+])/g,"\\$1")

Comment: How can you call `replace` on an INVALID string?

Comment: @Earth Engine: You paste the string as input, rather than as a literal.  Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ULhNS/

Comment: For your `C:\What` example, my code is actually working in this case,although `\W` has special meaning as in a regular expression, but what I actually need is just the fact `/C:\What/.toString()` returns `C:\What`, and that is true.

Comment: The fact is that too many escaping slashes affects the readability of code,so pasting as input and then use the output as code does not help. That is why we have `@""` literal in C#. So what I have did is to prove that even with current Javascript language we can still do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the double quotes in the string just wrap it with single quotes.

```
s = '"C:\\My Documents\\My Folder\\MyFile.file"'
console.log(s) // Output => "C:\My Documents\My Folder\MyFile.file"
```

Comment: I want to avoid that lot of double back slashes, since it prevent me from pasting paths.

Comment: @Earth Engine: I think the root of the problem is that there are lots of reasons why you can't always paste paths right into a regular expression.  What about paths with these characters in them? . & + ^

Comment: As long as the RegExp is not actually used for real string inputs, it is NOT a problem. The ONLY error can occur is at the end of the parse string. Actually I am going to force an ignored `!` char at the end to avoid problems.